# How to reference previous row after using pandas groupby on two indexes?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm utlizing Pandas to groupby two indexes. After performing groupby calculation, Id liek to create a two new columns that refer to the previous row.

See code below

```
import pandas as pd

ipl_data = {
   'Team': ['Riders', 'Riders', 'Devils', 'Devils', 'Kings','kings', 'Kings', 'Kings', 'Riders', 'Royals', 'Royals', 'Riders'],
   'Rank': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3,4,1,1,2,4,1,2],
   'Year': [2014,2015,2014,2015,2014,2015,2016,2017,2016,2014,2015,2017],
   'Points':[876,789,863,673,741,812,756,788,694,701,804,690]}
df = pd.DataFrame(ipl_data)
df.groupby(['Team','Year']).agg({'Points':sum})
```

See current output below

[image]

The desired output would have a new column for previous year and previous_year_points. For example, the second row would have 863 for Devils previous_year_points and 2014 for Devils previous_year.

My goal is to be able to reference the previous year of a specific team within each row.

I've tried the following but it did not work:

```
df.groupby(['Team','Year'])['Points'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1))
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
import pandas as pd

ipl_data = {
   'Team': ['Riders', 'Riders', 'Devils', 'Devils', 'Kings','kings', 'Kings', 'Kings', 'Riders', 'Royals', 'Royals', 'Riders'],
   'Rank': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3,4,1,1,2,4,1,2],
   'Year': [2014,2015,2014,2015,2014,2015,2016,2017,2016,2014,2015,2017],
   'Points':[876,789,863,673,741,812,756,788,694,701,804,690]}
df = pd.DataFrame(ipl_data)
dfg = df.groupby(['Team','Year']).agg({'Points':sum})

dfg['Prev Points'] = dfg.groupby('Team').shift()
dfg
```

Output:

```
             Points  Prev Points
Team   Year                     
Devils 2014     863          NaN
       2015     673        863.0
Kings  2014     741          NaN
       2016     756        741.0
       2017     788        756.0
Riders 2014     876          NaN
       2015     789        876.0
       2016     694        789.0
       2017     690        694.0
Royals 2014     701          NaN
       2015     804        701.0
kings  2015     812          NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
newdf = df.groupby(['Team','Year']).agg({'Points':sum}).reset_index()

newdf[['Year1', 'Points1']]= newdf.groupby('Team').apply(lambda x: x[['Year', 'Points']].shift())
newdf

      Team  Year  Points   Year1  Points1
0   Devils  2014     863     NaN      NaN
1   Devils  2015     673  2014.0    863.0
2    Kings  2014     741     NaN      NaN
3    Kings  2016     756  2014.0    741.0
4    Kings  2017     788  2016.0    756.0
5   Riders  2014     876     NaN      NaN
6   Riders  2015     789  2014.0    876.0
7   Riders  2016     694  2015.0    789.0
8   Riders  2017     690  2016.0    694.0
9   Royals  2014     701     NaN      NaN
10  Royals  2015     804  2014.0    701.0
11   kings  2015     812     NaN      NaN
```